# onClick action triggers immediately upon loading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question pertains to a single line of code within the Button Tag.

```
let content =  this.props.searchResult.map((ele, i) => {
  let card_id = ele.user.username + "_card";
  return(
    <div className="col s12 m6 l4" key={i} id={card_id}>
      <div className="card hoverable">
      <ProfileCard user={ele} eleIndex ={i} searchUserLevel={this.props.searchUserLevel}/>
        <div className="card-action">
          <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light orange"
           type="submit" name="action" onClick={ this.addPotentialClient(ele.user.username) } >
           Add<i className="material-icons right">add</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
});
```

In the code above upon loading the page the onClick action triggers, from the Button tag triggers.

With the code below the onClick action is only triggered on clicking, which is the desired property.

```
let content =  this.props.searchResult.map((ele, i) => {
  let card_id = ele.user.username + "_card";
    return(
      <div className="col s12 m6 l4" key={i} id={card_id}>
        <div className="card hoverable">
          <ProfileCard user={ele} eleIndex ={i} searchUserLevel={this.props.searchUserLevel}/>
          <div className="card-action">
           <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light orange"
            type="submit" name="action" onClick={ () => {this.addPotentialClient(ele.user.username)} } >
                    Add<i className="material-icons right">add</i>
            </button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>);
  });
```

What exactly is the difference between the invocations of the function?

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/gojz1yqv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second block you have

```
onClick={ () => {this.addPotentialClient(ele.user.username)} }
```

this is equivalent to:

```
var that = this;
...
onClick={function() {that.addPotentialClient(ele.user.username)} }
```

However the first block is

```
onClick={ this.addPotentialClient(ele.user.username) }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var value = this.addPotentialClient(ele.user.username);
...
onClick={ value }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On Reacts official page they have an [example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html), I am wondering why in this example they could just assign the function directly to the onClick property and why I had to register mine as a callback.

Comment: you can also do `this.addPotentialClient = this.addPotentialClient.bind(this)` in your constructor then you can have `onClick={ this.addPotentialClient }` Notice the lack of parenthesis ().